# ThreeJS: Some material texture faces / triangles not rendering

Tags: three.js

I have a .obj and .mtl which load textures from .tga files. This all seems to work / look fine in 3D modeling software, but when loaded with three.js (`THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })`) some of the object's children, (specifically between the knees and the calves, but not, for example, the pockets and legs), seem to have a **transparent jagged gap** / empty triangles.

(*Tried turning on antialiasing, changing the overdraw value, turning off transparency, etc.*)

Loader function:

```js
threejsHelper.helpers.loadObject('objects/pants/MaleBaggyPants.obj', 'objects/pants/MaleBaggyPants.mtl', {
    blinn1SG: (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, transparent: false, opacity: 1.0, overdraw: 0.5, map: threejsHelper.helpers.loadTexture(app.manager, 'objects/pants/button.tga') })),
    blinn2SG: (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, transparent: false, opacity: 1.0, overdraw: 0.5, map: threejsHelper.helpers.loadTexture(app.manager, 'objects/pants/back.tga') })),
    blinn4SG: (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, transparent: false, opacity: 1.0, overdraw: 0.5, map: threejsHelper.helpers.loadTexture(app.manager, 'objects/pants/front.tga') })),
    blinn5SG: (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, transparent: false, opacity: 1.0, overdraw: 0.5, map: threejsHelper.helpers.loadTexture(app.manager, 'objects/pants/pocket.tga') })),
    blinn6SG: (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, transparent: false, opacity: 1.0, overdraw: 0.5, map: threejsHelper.helpers.loadTexture(app.manager, 'objects/pants/back.tga') })),
    blinn7SG: (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, transparent: false, opacity: 1.0, overdraw: 0.5, map: threejsHelper.helpers.loadTexture(app.manager, 'objects/pants/front.tga') }))
}, function (object) {
    object.rotation.x = (-90*Math.PI/180);
    object.rotation.z = (-90*Math.PI/180);
    app.scene.add(object);
    app.ready = true;
});
```

Helper functions:

```js
...
loadTexture: function (manager, path) {
    var texture;
    if (path.split('.').pop() == 'tga') {
        var loader = new THREE.TGALoader();
        texture = loader.load(path);
    } else {
        texture = new THREE.Texture();
        var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
        loader.load(path, function (image) {
            texture.image = image;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
        });
    }
    return texture;
},
loadMaterial: function (mtlPath, textures, complete) {
    var loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    loader.load(mtlPath, function (materials) {
        materials.preload();
        if (!!materials.materials) {
            for (var key in materials.materials) {
                if (key in textures) {
                    materials.materials[key] = textures[key];
                }
            }
        }
        complete(materials);
    });
},
loadObject: function (objPath, mtlPath, textures, complete) {
    app.helpers.loadMaterial(mtlPath, textures, function (materials) {
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        loader.setMaterials(materials);
        loader.load(objPath, function (object) {
            complete(object);
        });
    });
},
...
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Try setting `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`. Also, remove overdraw -- that is for `CanvasRenderer` only.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the tip! Though, the gaps are still present. *(Tried overdraw with the CanvasRenderer as well - `var renderer = window.WebGLRenderingContext ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true }) : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();`)*

Comment: See if you can provide a link to a live example. Create a simpler obj file that duplicates the problem, and remove textures, as they should not be relevant.

Comment: @WestLangley will do... though, this doesn't happen with the other two .obj's, their .mtl's (a shoe and a dress) -- but they both use .png's (the above problem uses .tga's for the textures though, which i thought was the issue, but isn't).

Comment: @WestLangley http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/index.html

Comment: Simpler, please. Use `three.js`, not `three.min.js`. The scene should have one child -- the object that is the problem. I can't debug your app. Copy a three.js example. Use `OrbitControls` if you want.

Comment: Three.js / three.min.js standard lib / same code -- not asking you to check the quality of their code. Unfortunately, OrbitControls wasn't sufficient. Scenes may contain more than a single object. Thanks for your help ... but if you mean what I think you mean by "I can't debug your app" that's why I offered a bounty :)

Comment: As a three.js developer, I am glad to investigate if this is a three.js problem or a problem with your model. Whether I help you or not is up to you.

Comment: @WestLangley stripped down to the bare bones, same link. Important files are: `http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/app.js`, `http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/scripts/three.helper.js`, `http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/objects/pants-test/leg.obj`, `http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/objects/pants-test/leg.mtl`, `http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/objects/pants-test/frontpants.tga`

Comment: The OBJ file is not accessible, unfortunately... So the loader is returning a group with two child meshes, and the artifacts are at a seam between the two meshes. My guess is the missing triangles have one vertex in the first set and another other vertex in the other set. So the question is: is the OBJ file invalid, or is there a bug in the three.js loader?

Comment: Oddly, putting the link within ticks added some extra encoding before the final slash when you copy-paste from above... this should work: http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/objects/pants-test/leg.obj

Comment: And the obj should be fine... finder quick look renders it as such (no gap): http://matisseverduyn.com/cdn/static/demo/screenshots/leg.png

Comment: This looks like a three.js bug to me. As I suspected, the artifacts are on the seam between two meshes. File a bug report on the three.js site. Good luck! :)

Comment: @WestLangley thanks!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but code starting at line 306 in OBJLoader.js seems to imply a fixed side limit/requirement for all faces. The obj file in question shows some faces with more than 4 sides. For example see line 60067 in the obj file. There are more after. It's as if a cut tool has healed cut seams with complex faces. I wonder if a triangulation routine in the originating 3d editor before export to obj would help whilst waiting for a bug resolution....

Comment: @Radio ah geez, thought you and 2pha were the same person -- TYVM as well for digging this far into the issue also... though I awarded him the bounty for your joint effort 

Comment: @MatisseVerDuyn No worries. I'm not here for bounty, just interesting problems to solve. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have extra vertices along the seem on both the objects which I think will screw with the triangulation.
Remove these vertices that are not needed and I'm 99% sure it will fix your problem.

[image: extra vertices]

I also noticed the model is at a very small scale.

Comment: I noticed this too. noted it in the comments on OP's post. I think Removal will leave a gap. A triangulation pass on the model is a better bet. Alternatively the OBJLoader could be rewritten to triangulate faces with 4+ sides. See line 60067 in the obj file to see a face defined with 6 vertexes. OBJLoader.js allows a fourth vertex at line 321, but no more, hence the unclosed faces in Three.js.

Comment: To 2pha and @Radio - Thank you for your interest in this issue!

Comment: @2pha Thanks for digging this far into the issue -- I'll award you the bounty for actually finding the root of the problem. But unfortunately, I have to use what I get (these .obj files are served from Second Life) ... and if they can be rendered correctly by other software (example from finder quick look / preview above), then they should be able to be rendered correctly with three.js as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Some triangle didn't properly render on Threejs while it properly rendered on my OpenGL app.

I solved this trouble by using Uint32Array instead of Uint16Array to define the index of the geometry. I just put this line of code and everything worked like a charm.

```
const indices = new Uint32Array(faceDict.index);
```